# Accessing u16 type using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying the following piece code, i see crash in the printf statement.

```
typedef u16 skip_data

skip_data item1;

find_row(&item1);

find_row(skip_data *skip)
{
    int plane = 1;
    printf(" %d ", skip[plane]);

}
```

Is this the right way of accessing data? Excuse me for asking very basic question.

Comment: That code won't even compile, for numerous reasons, so I doubt you're seeing any kind of crash.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing memory at an invalid index.  If you change `plane` to 0, it should work fine.  Array/pointer access in "C" is 0 based.

You could also just do this:  `printf(" %d ", *skip);`

Additionally, don't forget to initialize `item1` to a value (e.g. `item1 = 0;`).   The way you have it, `item1` holds random data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.In the code is see they have used skip[plane] and this can be either 0 or 1 and seems to work.  But when i try to assign skip[plane] to a variable, i see crash.

Answer (score -1):

-1 come on guys!
//where is the typedef for u16 is it an unsigned short (word) or an array definition?

```
typedef unsigned short skip_data[10]//create a memory space for 10 'u16's

skip_data item1[1] = 500;

find_row(item1);//NOTE: no need for address for array

find_row(skip_data skip)
{
    int plane = 1;
    printf(" %d ", skip[plane]);//displays '500'

}
```